# Can one transfer an object's animation data between seperate projects?

Tags: animation

I had made two copies of a robot that I animated in full in one but unfortunately messed up the parenting within its limbs to a point of irreversibility.

Is it possible for me to copy only the animation I have linked to each limb on the new ruined copy back over to the old workable copy without having to redo the entire animation process again?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy data blocks from one blender file to another using the Append functionality. Though this will only work if both your rigs are the same.

Step by step process :

- Open your 'old workable' Blender file, to which the animation needs to be imported.
- Go to File > Append.
- In the file browser, select the blender file from which animation needs to be copied. Go to Action folder, and append the required animation clip.
- Assign the appended action to your working rig using the Action Editor window.

Hope this helps !